# How do return the number of times a value in a column does not line up with another value in another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df :

```
>>> df
           user_id     group      landing_page    converted

          12345       control      old_page          0
          12346       treatment    new_page          1
          12347       control      new_page          1
          12345       treatment    old_page          0
          12349       treatment    old_page          1
```

I want to return the number of times treatment does not line up with new_page.

I have tried `df[(df['group' == "treatment"]) != (df['landing_page'] == 'new_page')]` However, I keep getting errors.

Also, is there a way to get the mean of converted by using unique users?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you are looking for

```
>>> ((df['group'] == 'treatment') & (df['landing_page'] != 'new_page')).sum()
2
```

Details:

```
>>> df['group'] == 'treatment'
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: group, dtype: bool
>>> 
>>> df['landing_page'] != 'new_page'
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: landing_page, dtype: bool
>>> 
>>> (df['group'] == 'treatment') & (df['landing_page'] != 'new_page')
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
>>>
>>> ((df['group'] == 'treatment') & (df['landing_page'] != 'new_page')).sum()
2
```

Comment: Just as a comment, all those separated parentheses can get confusing: for readability one may prefer: `(df['group'].eq('treatment') & df['landing_page'].ne('new_page')).sum()`

Answer (score 0):

## Question 1:

IIUC, you just need to do:

```
len(df[(df.group=='treatment') & (df.landing_page != 'new_page')])
```

which outputs:

```
2
```

More generally, you can get all the counts for the combinations of `group` and `treatment` using `groupby`:

```
>>> df.groupby(['group','landing_page']).size()
group      landing_page
control    new_page        1
           old_page        1
treatment  new_page        1
           old_page        2
dtype: int64
```

Showing that you have only 1 `treatment` group that with `new_page`, and 2 `treatment` groups with `old_page`

## Question 2:

Groupby the `user_id`, and get the mean of `converted` column:

```
df.groupby('user_id').converted.mean()

# user_id
# 12345    0
# 12346    1
# 12347    1
# 12349    1
# Name: converted, dtype: int64
```